# Get orderId from quote_item

Tags: magento2, quoteitem

I have an instance of `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item`

I need to get the order ID of the order in which that particular item has been purchased.

For full disclosure, I am using a plugin function called afterConvert,
which operates around the function "convert" in

```
Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem
```

Anyway, the table for quote_item doesn't seem to have the order_id in it.

Any idea how I could go about it?

```
public function aroundConvert(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item,
    $additional = []
) {
    $order = null;

    $item->getQuote();

    $options = $this->configurationHelper->getOptions($item);

    foreach ($options as $option){
        if($option['label'] == 'Clarity'){
            $clarity = $option['value'];
        }
        if($option['label'] == 'Color'){
            $color = $option['value'];
        }
        if($option['label'] == 'Shape'){
            $shape = $option['value'];
        }
        if($option['label'] == 'Carat'){
            $carat = $option['value'];
        }
    }
    /** @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Api\Data\ConfigurableItemOptionValueInterface $option */

    $qrcode = $this->qrcodeFactory->create();
    $orderID = $item->getOrderId();
```

But `$item->getOrderId` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this.

The trick is to use this event:

```
sales_model_service_quote_submit_success
```

This way you are sure that:

A) The order actually went through

B) The orderId exists, because the event fires after

`$order = $this->orderManagement->place($order);`

in the function

`protected function submitQuote(QuoteEntity $quote, $orderData = [])`

that you can find here

`Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement`

So I used an Observer instead of a Plugin!

Answer (score 0):

The quote is an order that it has **not been passed yet**, so since it has not been passed yet, you can't get his **order ID**.

If you want to get the `order id` of some product from the quote, it's not like this, you have instead to get all orders, then in this all orders you get them products, afterthat you compare if the orders contain one of your current quote `product_id`, so you get his `order_id` or `order_id's`.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Problem was "orderId" didn't exist yet!